# What are the files stored for a Windows 7 Backup? Or the Seagate backup?

Tags: backup, windows-7-backup

When I got a backup drive, I was undecided whether to use the backup feature in Windows 7, or to use the Seagate utility that came with the drive. I had space enough for two backups, so I let them both run. Now, I'd like to use that drive to copy over my documents, Steam games, downloads, etc, but I'm unsure as to which directories to delete to get just the Windows backup on there (which seems like it would be more likely to allow a systems restore). I've disabled the Seagate backup, but that doesn't actually remove the files.

[image: Image of my backup drive]

Worse comes to worse, I can probably delete everything, copy over the vital files, move them over, and them just do the Windows backup fresh, but it takes time to delete and/or move files, so I'd prefer to only delete what I have to.

**Image of the SEAN-PC Folder:**
[image: Image of the SEAN-PC Folder]

**Image of the WindowsImageBackup/Sean-PC Folder** (Sean-PC being the only subfolder):
[image: Image of the WindowsImageBackup/Sean-PC Folder]

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official site of Seagate](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/212797en?language=en-as), the default location is:

`C: -> Users -> Username -> Documents`

But if you changed the default location already, in that case this should not work.

**Edit:**

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no folder in your `Backup (F:)` drive that is corresponded to Seagate Dashboard unless hidden. Both the Folders `SEAN-PC` and `WindosImageBackup` is directly attached to Windows Backup.

Comment: Hmm... I added an image of my backup drive, which suggests that this does not match what I am seeing.

Comment: Can you remember the exact name of the Seagate utility you used as they have many similar utilities

Comment: "Seagate Dashboard"

Comment: can you please upload two more images one after opening the `SEAN-PC` Drive and another image opening the `WindosImageBackup` Drive in your Backup drive. And please provide the individual sizes of those two folders

Comment: Done and done. There was only one folder in WindowsImageBackup.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Both the folders `SEAN-PC` and `WindosImageBackup ` is directly attached to Windows Backup.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Now I am most thoroughly baffled. :)

Comment: @SeanDuggan If this is the correct answer too your problem, please mark it as accepted

Comment: Are those the only directories involved then?

Comment: Yes, those  are the only directories involved